# How can I modify this extension method accept two string parameters?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, linq-to-entities

I have the following extension method which behaves like a `SQL IN`:

```
 public static IQueryable<TEntity> WhereIn<TEntity, TValue>
  (
    this ObjectQuery<TEntity> query,
    Expression<Func<TEntity, TValue>> selector,
    IEnumerable<TValue> collection
  )
    {
        if (selector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("selector");
        if (collection == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("collection");
        if (!collection.Any())
            return query.Where(t => false);

        ParameterExpression p = selector.Parameters.Single();

        IEnumerable<Expression> equals = collection.Select(value =>
           (Expression)Expression.Equal(selector.Body,
                Expression.Constant(value, typeof(TValue))));

        Expression body = equals.Aggregate((accumulate, equal) =>
            Expression.Or(accumulate, equal));

        return query.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(body, p));
    }



      //Optional - to allow static collection:
        public static IQueryable<TEntity> WhereIn<TEntity, TValue>
          (
            this ObjectQuery<TEntity> query,
            Expression<Func<TEntity, TValue>> selector,
            params TValue[] collection
          )
        {
            return WhereIn(query, selector, (IEnumerable<TValue>)collection);
        }
```

The problem is that when I call it like this:

```
predicate = predicate.And(x => WhereIn(x.id, Ids));
```

It gives me an error:  `The type arguments for method 'WhereIn<TEntity,TValue>(System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<TEntity>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TEntity,TValue>>, params TValue[])' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explictly.`

`x.id is a Ids are both of type string.`

I actually don't want to change the method signaure, I would rather change the call to it, but I am not sure what to put in between the brackets of `WhereIn<>`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're calling the extension method wrong.

Try like this:

```
predicate = predicate.And(x => x.WhereIn(x.id, Ids));
```

Comment: I put my WhereIn extension in a static class called Extensions, so I don't see x.WhereIn, so it is something like Extensions.WhereIn.

Comment: if you don't see x.WhereIn it means either you don't have the namespace of the Extensions class in a using statement, OR x is not of type ObjectQuery<TEntity>.

Comment: x is a Person entity in my case.

Comment: How about `predicate = predicate.And(x => Extensions.WhereIn(x, x.id, Ids));`

Comment: It still tells me type arguments can't be inferred from usage.

Comment: How about `predicate = predicate.And(x => Extensions.WhereIn<Person, string>(x, x.id, Ids));`

Comment: This semi-works, but it wants me to create an overload which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30929/discussion-between-robsiklos-and-xaisoft)